# Add more MFA devices to AWS root user. "You can assign a maximum of 8 MFA devices."

Tags: amazon-web-services, multi-factor-authentication

I realise that there are already similar questions asked about this topic.

I have just had to create a password for amazon AWS, that's separate from my normal amazon 'shopping' account password. Fine.

Then I go to turn on Multi Factor Authentication, but I can only add one yubikey, or one Auth App.  Where I've done this; right there where I see my newly-added MFA device, it says "You can assign a maximum of 8 MFA devices."  How do I add another one?

If I cannot add another, why does it say "You can assign a maximum of 8 MFA devices."? Bizzare?  Hopefully, I've got it wrong...

thanks for any help you can give...

Answer (score -1):

[Looks to be a roll out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV9v9.png) I ran across your question while searching for answer myself. I stumbled across this reddit post, and this appears to be a feature still being rolled out. Thought I would provide this answer here too just in case it helps someone else in the futur .

Comment: Please do not put links to images. Try and copy paste the content of reddit post into your answer instead.